# Query: All employee with sum of salary > 500

Tags: mysql

In my MYSQL Database COMPANY, I have a Table: `Worker` :

```
mysql> DESC `Worker`;
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SSN    | varchar(64) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name   | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| salary | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I created using following MySQL's command:

```
CREATE TABLE `Worker` (
  `SSN` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salary` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The table having following data:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `Worker` ORDER BY salary ASC;
+-----+---------+--------+
| SSN | name    | salary |
+-----+---------+--------+
| 6   | TWO     |     50 |
| 5   | ONE     |    100 |
| 1   | Grijesh |    200 |
| 3   | Sumit   |    250 |
| 2   | Rahul   |    300 |
| 4   | Harsh   |    500 |
| 7   | THREE   |   1000 |
+-----+---------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

its insert query:

```
INSERT INTO `Worker`
    (SSN, name, salary) 
  VALUES 
    ("1", "Grijesh", 200),
    ('2','Rahul',300),
    ('3','Sumit',250),
    ('4','Harsh',500),
    ('5','ONE','100'),
    ('6','TWO',50),
    ('7','THREE',1000);
```

**[QUESTION]**

I wants to select first *n* `workers` (*in asc list*)those sum of salary is just more than 500 (> 500). for example:

following four workers are first low salary employees and having SUM of salary 600. (600 > 500)

```
| 6   | TWO     |     50 |
| 5   | ONE     |    100 |
| 1   | Grijesh |    200 |
| 3   | Sumit   |    250 |
```

I need something like `SELECT *  FROM`Worker`WHERE SUM(salary) < 501 ASC;`  (its incorrect query)

An assumption can be made that all having different salary.

<sub>its something like cost cutting: remove employee those are relatively unimportant</sub>

A suggestion or link to read will be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After playing around with this some more, I came up with [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/643f3/24) query:

```
SELECT ssn, name, salary FROM (
  SELECT ssn, name, salary, (@total:=@total+salary) as total
  FROM worker, (select @total:=0) t
  ORDER BY salary ASC
) as foo
WHERE (total-salary) <=500
```

This seems to do what you want on this limited data, but could be very slow on large datasets.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution, but it looks ugly. There may be a better solution without a subquery.

```
SELECT ssn, name, salary, prev_accum, accum from
(
    SELECT *, @a AS prev_accum, @a:= @a + salary AS accum 
    FROM Worker, (select @a :=0) as dummy
    ORDER BY salary
) AS dummy2
WHERE prev_accum < 500;
```

If you run this query in phpmyadmin, there is a display error, which shows BLOB for variable. You will need the following casting.

```
SELECT ssn, name, salary, CAST(prev_accum as decimal) prev_accum, accum from
(
    SELECT *, @a AS prev_accum, @a:= @a + salary AS accum 
    FROM Worker, (select @a :=0) as dummy
    ORDER BY salary
) AS dummy2
WHERE prev_accum < 500;
```

Comment: I had something similar in my answer, but updated it to its current form to avoid the potential issue described in the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//user-variables.html) of reading/writing from the same user variable and adhering to the recommendation "As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement." Like `SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1`